# Working with one or two software companies? (CMS and E-Commerce)

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce

**Background**

We are a B2B company with no in-house developers. We're current outsourcing all our development work to a small software company. They've built their own custom CMS, which we are using.

At the moment, we're in a redesign phase where a new website is being build by this same software company, again tailored to work with their custom build CMS.

At the same time, we are planning to have a webshop, which is going to be built by a different company, a big E-Commerce software company.

**What we need**

In the end it should be one website, on the same domain. Where content and commerce should go hand in hand. Everything should be seamlessly integrated with each other, for example the search function (they both offer their own search engine), content and products.

**Wouldn't it make more sense to let one company build everything instead of two different companies? What are plus or downsides to work with one or two companies in this case? Where could it go wrong?**

I'm a bit scared when we work with two partners, that the total cost of ownership is going to rise to the moon. That it will bring a lot of inefficiencies with it and we're hindered when it comes to further scaling.

P.S. I'm not a final decision maker within this company, but I'm looking for input in order to change the current plan (which is working with two partners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting scenario that you are in here.

`Wouldn't it make more sense to let one company build everything instead of two different companies?`

Based on your description there is nothing in this that is particularly out of the ordinary. A website for your company with an online shop. There is no good reason why you need two contractors. What I mean here, is that there is no reason why one company cannot provide the expertise to deliver both parts. Adding a second company / contractor will add more complexity to the situation and therefore breaks the generally good rule of keep it simple. (More on this later).

`What are plus or downsides to work with one or two companies in this case?`

The positive of working with two companies is that you can get experts in the different areas. For example if company A is an expert in one part of the solution and company B is an expert in another you get the combined expertise. However, in this case there doesn't seem to be a need for this.

`Where could it go wrong?`

This is very much the downside of having two companies working on this. The two companies will need to work together to provide the solution. This is likely to require some management from you (or your company) which you correctly identify the cost of ownership can significantly increase. You run the risk of both of your contractors pointing the finger at each other when things go wrong.

I would strongly recommend at least considering using a single company for the whole project delivering a combined website and online shop.

Comment: Thank you James for your input. The part you've mentioned with 'pointing the finger at each other', is something I had in my mind as well.

Comment: As you've said: they have to work together, to make it work in the end. But on what parts do they especially need to work together:

- Integrating everything into one website?
- Two different search engines?
- Content pages with products on it?

Where are the parts where they will meet?

Comment: There are a lot of places where they will meet. Working on the same domain they will need to ensure there aren't any URI clashes. Because it is a single website and shop they will need to keep a consistent style. If you wish to hold session data between the shop and the rest of the website they will have to integrate/share cookies.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, my list of where they could possibly meet got even bigger. Thank you so much for that. Could you let me know whenever you know any other points where they could possibly 'clash' or meet eachother? Maybe points that occur relatively often in similar projects? Greetings.